# Deleting rows where the Primary key is duplicated - SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, rows

My issue is how do we delete a primary key row in case it is duplicated. The other fields may/may not be duplicates. I am interested only in the primary key being duplicated and would like to retain the first instance while deleting the other duplicate entries.

For example,

I have 2 tables with the following data:

Table1:- **Portfolio**

Columns:- **PortfolioID(PK), PortfolioName**

Sample data :-

> 1, North America
>   2, Europe
>    3, Asia

Table2:- **Account**

Columns:- **AccountID(PK), PortfolioID(FK), AccountName**

Sample data :-

> 1,1,Quake
>
> 1,1,Wind
>
> 2,1,Fire
>
> 3,1,Quake
>
> 4,2,Flood
>
> 5,2,Wind

Lets say for PortfolioID = 1,
I am trying to delete row number 2 from the Account table where the AccountID 1 is repeated for PortfolioID =1. I have tried using the CTE expression where I use the ROW_NUMBER statement and try to delete ROWNUMBER <> 1. But this query doesn't work as it deletes all the rows in the table.

The query I tried:

```
    WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Account].[AccountID] ORDER BY [Account].[AccountID]) AS [ROWNUMBER],
    [Account].[AccountID]
    FROM [Account]
   INNER JOIN [Portfolio] ON [Portfolio].[PortfolioID] = [Account]. [PortfolioID]
   WHERE [Portfolio].[PortfolioID] = 1
   )

 DELETE [Account]
 FROM   [CTE] 
 WHERE  [ROWNUMBER] <> 1
```

Am I doing something wrong in the query? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How can a primary key column have duplicate values? Are you sure about your question?

Comment: AccountID is obviously not the table's primary key, for otherwise it would simply not be possible to have duplicates. However, so far I cannot spot any error in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you define the AccountID column as the primary key in your database, this going forward will help solve having these kinds of problems.

Secondly, are you using Sql Server?  Which version?

Assuming you are using Sql Server and a recent version which allows you to use windowing, you can try something like this to delete any duplicates that you have.

This will delete ALL copies of ALL duplicates:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *,R=RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AccountID,PortfolioID)
FROM Account)

DELETE CTE
WHERE R IN (SELECT R FROM CTE GROUP BY R HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

This alternative script will keep one of the duplicates if that is what you prefer:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID,PortfolioID ORDER BY     AccountID,PortfolioID) AS RN
FROM Account
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

Finally, if you want to only delete duplicates for Portfolio Id 1:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID,PortfolioID ORDER BY     AccountID,PortfolioID) AS RN
FROM Account
Where PortfolioID = 1
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

Comment: I guess I failed to mention that I dropped the PK constraint on the Account table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this query works if we are not joining the tables. But say we are joining multiple tables, for eg, Portfolio linked to Account on PortfolioID, Account linked to Policy on Account ID, and I have duplicates in my Policy table in the field PolicyID (PK). How would I write the delete statement I wish to delete duplicate rows in the Policy table? DELETE [Policy] FROM CTE WHERE RN <> 1 doesn't work for me. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Honestly if you have multiple tables with duplicate issues I would work through them one table at a time.  If you want to delete duplicates from the policy table rather than the account table, you have to change the CTE code, not just the delete.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key column never ever support duplicate entries.

Try with the below query for the desired result based on the given data/inputs.

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[AccountID],a.PortfolioID ORDER BY a.[AccountID]) AS [ROWNUMBER],*
    FROM [Account] a
   WHERE a.[PortfolioID] = 1
   )
   DELETE
   FROM   [CTE] 
   WHERE  [ROWNUMBER] > 1
```